# Como exportar a un archivo txt las filas REPETIDAS de un DataGridView

Tags: c#

Necesito exportar a archivos txt todo lo que contiene un DataGridView (cada fila un archivo) pero en el caso de que una celda de una columna determinada tenga el mismo valor se debe exportar esas dos fila en un solo archivo.

Por el momento exporto los archivos que estén seleccionados

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);


for (int i = 0; i < TablaDatos.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[Exportar.Name].Value) == true)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells)
        {
            data += (cell.Value + "\t");
        }
        data += "\n";
    }

}


tw.WriteLine(data, "data");
tw.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Datos exportados correctamente");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito exportar todo el Grid que sea un archivo por fila, pero, si tienen la misma categoría, exportar cada fila dentro de en un mismo archivo txt, si en todo el Grid existe solo un archivo con la categoria 8 por ejemplo, esa fila sera un archivo txt.

Comment: "== true" no es necesario.

Comment: no entiendo bien, eso lo quieres a un archivo diferente ?? puedes desarrollar un poco mas?

Comment: editare la pregunta para dejarlo claro, gracias por su comentarios

Comment: @AbregoW no evaluaste aplicar la tecnica que comente en tu pregunta anterior ? si vuelvas los datos del grid a una clase que tu defines podrias usar linq para agrupar y generar con esto varios archivos

Comment: Leandro Tunttini no he podido utilizar la libreria filehelpers, de que otra forma se podria hacer ya que quiero exportar todas las filas que tengan la misma categoria en un mismo txt y la fila que no tenga el mismo id de categoria sera un archivo txt, gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: Hola abrego, cual ha sido el problema de utilizar la libreria que menciona @LeandroTuttini ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas seguro ya encontraste una solucion a tu problema, pero quería compartir un codigo similar que puedes aplicar a tu control DataGridView con unas modificaciones, en mi version, he utilizado una clase llamada `Articulos` e hice una lista para dividirla y un array de strings para las categorías, cabe mencionar que el ejemplo es en consola.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Categorias.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filtrados por Categoria: " + Categorias[i]);
        foreach (Articulo n in Articulos)
        {
            if (n.Categoria == Categorias[i])
                Console.WriteLine(n.ID + "\t" + n.Valor);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Donde he usado estos datos como entrada:

```
// Arreglo de categorias según necesidades.
public static string[] Categorias = new string[] { "Hogar", "Comida", "Ropa" };

public static IList<Articulo> Articulos = new List<Articulo>()
{
    new Articulo(1, Categorias[0], 100), new Articulo(2, Categorias[1], 200),
    new Articulo(3, Categorias[2], 500), new Articulo(4, Categorias[1], 300),
    new Articulo(5, Categorias[2], 800), new Articulo(6, Categorias[0], 400),
    new Articulo(7, Categorias[1], 100), new Articulo(8, Categorias[2], 750),
    new Articulo(9, Categorias[0], 690)
};
```

El cual arroja la siguiente salida:

```
Filtrados por Categoria: Hogar
1    100
6    400
9    690
Filtrados por Categoria: Comida
2    200
4    300
7    100
Filtrados por Categoria: Ropa
3    500
5    800
8    750
```

Ahí te dejo el [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLJYOu) del fiddle, espero te ayude!